# Why is the associative rule of a binary operation actually binary, even if it uses 3 variables?

Tags: abstract-algebra

(consider $+$ to be an arbitrary operation; any operation that works on a field)

$(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is associative, when...: $x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z$

can I just define a binary(!) operation and expand it w/ as many as I want?

Plus one another question...
if I was saying...

$(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is commutative, when...: $x+y+z = x+z+y$

is that still a correct definition or do I have to show it for all combinations? although I don't think so, maybe  I could be surprised.

Comment: The map $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+y)+z$ is certainly not binary....it takes three arguments.  Note too that the map $(x,y,z)\mapsto x+y+z$ is ill-defined unless you have an associative binary operation.

Comment: Let $*$ be the binary operation that simply returns the first input... that is, $a*b = a$.  Notice that $*$ is associative here.  Here, we have that $a*b*c = a*c*b$ (*they are both equal simply to $a$*) for all $a,b,c$ despite $*$ not being commutative.

Comment: thanks!!! got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that an operation, e.g. $+$, is binary means that it takes two arguments.  The familiar $+$ with the integers, real numbers, and many other structures is binary.

Having defined a binary operation, you might want to explore its properties.  One property that is frequently considered is commutativity.  Checking this only requires using two arguments: is $x + y = y + x$?  Most common uses of $+$ have this property.  $\times$ is often commutative but exceptions are more common e.g. matrices.

However, some further interesting properties require using the operation more than once with more than two operands in total.  The property of being associative is an example: is $x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z$.  The operation is still binary, each of the four uses here has two operands (though some are the result of another usage).  That is possible to ask about the properties of multiple uses of the operator with more than two operands in total does not mean that the operation is not binary.  Both $+$ and $\times$ are usually associative but there are exceptions e.g. the cross product of vectors.

Most people have two biological parents, mother and father, but if you consider two generations back then most people have four biological grandparents.  The existence of four grandparents does not mean that two biological direct parents is not usual.

Comment: The property of being associative is an example: is x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z. The operation is still binary, each of the four uses here has two operands.

Don't u mean... six or three? or do u mean to focus on two variables each side?

Comment: @Amir The four refers to the $+$ operation, it occurs four times in the rule.  My point was that each of those four uses has the usual two operands.  For the first they are $x$ and $(y + z)$ so the second argument to this first use is the result of the second use.

Comment: I actually never knew that I could interpret it like that, ah. Now everything really makes sense, or maybe it was my sleep.